# Why this function is returning response as null

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I wrote a function on event click as below

```
$('#ClickMe').live('click', function () {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest({ method: "getT" }, function (response) {
        alert(response.data); // Displaying undefined..
    });
});
```

in background page..

```
function wish(){      
   return "Hey...";
}
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
  if (request.method == "getT"){
    sendResponse({data: wish()});
  }
  else
    sendResponse({});
});
```

I cannot get the response in Content Script.Please help me on this.

Comment: Have you tried adding `console.log()` statements to your background page to see what exactly is being called and when, as well as the value of `request.method`? The code looks fine to me and I can't think why it's not working.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the bug. How exactely do you run `$("#ClickMe".....);`?

Comment: @Rob W I cannot understand your point. Could you tell me what more inputs you want...

Comment: @ Alasdair I am also confused. It worked before and now returning me undefined when I am running this.. :-(

Comment: @SoI Did you put that code in your Content Script, without anything else? What's the content of `manifest.json`? If your content script is too big,consider pasting the code at http://pastebin.com/

Comment: @RobW Dont know why.. It is returning me exact result if i remove live and give normal click even like $('#selector').click(function(){});

Comment: Put your code in http://pastebin.com/. Your explanations are too vague to be helpful :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send functional parameters like that within a JSON object you would need to instantiate it first, and then pass it as a variable not as a function because it will treat it as a Closure, so when it does the serialization, it will not include that.

```
function wish(){      
   return "Hey...";
}
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
  if (request.method == "getT"){
    var data = wish();
    sendResponse({data: data});
  }
  else
    sendResponse({});
});
```

The above snippet should work.

Comment: Glad to have your response and Thanks for the answer.